# remove element from dom angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to properly remove element in dom model using angular directive?

```
.directive('restrict', ['AuthService', function (authService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        prioriry: 100000,
        scope: false,
        link: function () {
            alert('1');
        },
        compile: function (element, attr, linker) {
            var accessDenied = true;
            var user = authService.getUser();
            var attributes = attr.access.split(" ");

            for (var i in attributes) {
                if (user.roles.indexOf(attributes[i]) > -1) {
                    accessDenied = false;
                }
            }

            if (accessDenied) {
                element.children().remove();
                element.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

this code throw exception in last line:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

directive works well for td or li elements, but wrong for a or div or span

```
<span data-restrict access='EditUser' class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-click="deleteUser(u)"></span>
```

Comment: What happens if you just do element.remove() ? Without the previous line?

Comment: it works only for td, li elements...

Comment: what version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: Hmm that's quite an old version, note btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121248/what-is-the-best-practice-for-dependency-injection-annotation-with-angularjs/26123376#26123376

Comment: Can you replicate it in a [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co)?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do this, you could go a different approach, you could add a controller which sets a flag (accessDenied) on the scope based on the same condition, then use ng-if on your directive, or first child element failing that.

Comment: Can you show some code to explain what you mean exactly, please?